# Can I write this 'for' code in simpler terms? Perhaps using 'apply'?

Tags: r, for-loop, apply

Is there a way to write this code in simpler terms in R?

Perhaps using `apply`?

Thanks for any tip.

```
for(i in 1:nrow(mat1)){
  mat1$c8[i] = formula(mat1$c1[i], mat1$c2[i], mat1$c3[i], mat1$c4[i], mat1$c5[i], mat1$c6[i], mat1$c7[i])
}
```

Dataset:

```
mat <- data.frame(c1 = sample(1:3,  100, replace = TRUE), 
                  c2 = sample(1:4,  100, replace = TRUE), 
                  c3 = sample(1:2,  100, replace = TRUE), 
                  c4 = sample(1:2,  100, replace = TRUE), 
                  c5 = sample(0:1,  100, replace = TRUE), 
                  c6 = sample(0:1,  100, replace = TRUE), 
                  c7 = sample(0:1,  100, replace = TRUE)) 

mat1 <- mat

mat1
```

Comment: Is that `stats::formula` you are using? Seems strange...

Comment: Can you post here sample data from mat1?

Comment: @Gregor 'formula' is just the name of a function I created. Sorry for not being clear about that.

Comment: @mso This is the dataset of mat1

Comment: What is your expected output? What do you want c8 to be? You may give only one entry as an example to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like what you're trying to do is somewhat unusual, but if you insist on doing it, what you need is `Map()` or `mapply()`. These functions will call a function multiple times using a number of input vectors, combining the output in a list (`Map()`) or the simplest possible output (`mapply()`).

```
mat$c8 <- Map(formula, mat$c1, mat$c2, mat$c3, mat$c4, 
              mat$c5, mat$c6, mat$c7)
```

You could also roll that all together into a single line, although I think the above better communicates what you're trying to accomplish.

```
mat$c8 <- do.call(Map, c(list(formula), mat))
```

For a detailed overview on the `lapply()` family, the [functionals chapter](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functionals.html#functionals-loop) of [Advanced R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/) is quite good.

Comment: Cheers @paleolimbot This is very useful